# Can I login in with Facebook as an unregistered user? (Django, all-auth)

Tags: django, facebook, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, python-social-auth

I'm building my Django RESTful Framework to retrieve and post data for Mobile. I'm using djang-rest-auth (which is just all-auth with RESTful functionality; more info: http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Question: **Social Auth in all-auth is not clear to me. Can you finish this use case?**

Use Case: Unregistered User

1. User Login with Facebook on Mobile
2. Mobile gets facebook token from Facebook SDK
3. Mobile sends token to our DRF Backend server URL which is '/rest-auth/facebook'
4. **And what happens? Can you complete this Use Case?** **<- This is my question**

My guesses:

- all-auth automatically create new user for facebook user token and return new token?
- Then, it saves created user to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL? Or...?
- I found 'social account' in Django admin. Are we saving User in this account..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. After receiving facebook token Django will create `SocialAccount` instance which include backend name (facebook in your case) and facebook id of user. This instance will be related with `AUTH_USER_MODEL` by `ForeignKey` so when next time user will try to login Django will find `SocialAccount` by specified `facebook id` and return related `AUTH_USER_MODEL` instance.

Comment: Hi. I received token from Facebook and sent POST request with the token as 'access_token'. I'm getting 400 error... Any idea? I'm stock on this problem for a long time.

Comment: @JohnBaek sorry I dont have any idea. Can you post another question with more details?

Comment: Sure. Thanks. I've been stock with this problem for a week.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098317/my-access-token-from-facebook-is-incorrect-value