# My 'access_token' from facebook is "incorrect value"

Tags: facebook, react-native, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm using django-rest-auth which is "API extension for Django all-auth". I'm building a mobile app which can signup/login using Facebook token (url: http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/facebook/).

1. get Facebook token using 'expo'

   ```
   export const doFacebookLogin = () => async dispatch => {
     let { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('194632xxxxxx', {
         permissions: ['public_profile']
     });

     if (type === 'cancel') {
       return dispatch({ type: FACEBOOK_LOGIN_CANCEL })
     }
     doSocialAuthLogin(dispatch, token);
   };
   ```
2. Include token in Http POST request

   ```
   const doSocialAuthLogin = async (dispatch, token) => {
     console.log(token);
     axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/rest-auth/facebook/`, {
       access_token: token
     }).then(response => {
       AsyncStorage.setItem('stylee_token', response.data.token);
       dispatch({ type: AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response.data.token });
     })
     .catch(response => {
       if(response.status === 400) {
         console.log('Not authorized. ');
       } else if (response.status === 403){
         console.log('You are not suposed to see this message. Contact Administrator');
       }
       dispatch({ type: SOCIAL_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_FAIL });
     });
   }
   ```
3. I got 400 error. So I printed the token tested on localhost browser and Postman. And both returns

   ```
   {
       "non_field_errors": [
           "Incorrect value"
       ]
   }
   ```

Why am I getting 400 Incorrect value error?

- settings.py

  SITE_ID = 7 # I searched for corresponding SITE_ID from shell.
- admin

  Social_Application. =>

  ```
  provider: Facebook
  name: ~
  Client id:~
  Secret Key: ~
  Chosen Sites: 'http://localhost:8000'
  ```

**I think I put wrong value for 'access_token'. Can't we put token from expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync?. Since FB token changes over time.**

Comment: example) access_token : "sdkfnsdkfnslkefnefnsefjbsefjkbsekfjse"

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In the admin page for the social app (http://localhost:8000/admin/socialaccount/socialapp/1/change/), you need to specify the "secret key" for Facebook provider.